# release APK not working properly but every thing in debug APK is working perfectly fine

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter build some applications only. Currently, I  was working on a small project with API every this was fine but when I build the release of the application it starts showing nothing (no API are able to load data)and I am unable to find what is a problem with my app. Tried almost every possible this I can find out.

already given all the permission that is required for the application.

any help will be appreciated.
thank you in advance.

Comment: have you signed it correctly?

Comment: No problem in signing app gest blank when runner

Comment: Try debugging with flutter run --release, and check the output in terminal when error occur, then we'll know how to fix it furthermore

Answer (score 0):

Did you mentioned INTERNET permission in the mamifest file?

Comment: Yes .. given all necessary permission